# オーバーライドするメソッドの引数の型を変えたい

Tags: java

例えば、以下のようなコードで、引数 `msg` の型を `Message` を継承した `MyMessage` に変えたい場合、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

オーバーライドするメソッドがあるクラスに書き足すしか方法はないのでしょうか。

```
MessageHandler handlerReqNormalizedCardinal = new MessageHandler() {
    @Override
    public Message process(Message msg) throws Exception {
        return new RepNormalizedCardinalMessage(MyCFRTChord.this.routingTable.normalizedCardinal);
    }
};
```

Comment: キャストすれば良いのではないでしょうか。「MyMessage mymsg = (MyMessage)msg」

Comment: キャストすると継承して拡張した部分が消えるという先入観があって試しておりませんでした。つまり、`msg` には C 言語でいうポインタが入る認識なのですね。くだらないことを質問して、申し訳ないです；

Comment: いえいえ、お役に立てた様でよかったです。

Comment: それと、このサイトの決まりみたいなものがありまして、ご自身で解決された場合には、ご自身で回答する習わしになっております。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6):

キャストすると継承して拡張した部分が消えるという先入観があって試しておりませんでした。つまり、msg には C 言語でいうポインタが入る認識なのですね。くだらないことを質問して、申し訳ないです；